# Obvious duplicate with an answer - what should be done?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, duplicates, exact-duplicates

I asked [a question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194480/cannot-boot-android-x86-on-pc-emergency-remount?noredirect=1&lq=1) about 7 months ago, and then, [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/196108/android-x86-error-sysrq-emergency-remount-r-0?noredirect=1&lq=1) was asked - which was the exact same question, just reworded.

I flagged it as duplicate and left a comment saying that reposting questions is a bad idea, even if parts of it were changed.

However, the question also has an answer, saying that "this code helped me" (even though it is a link-only answer).

What would be the best practice for handling this question? My best guess would be:

- Close the question as duplicate.
- Migrate the answer.
- Edit the answer to include the GRUB code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've closed the other question as duplicate. With the only answer being link-only, I see no reason to merge it. Due to the dupe-closure, the two posts are linked together anyway, so it can be looked up easily. So in cases like this, you can vote-to-close if your reputation allows, or flag it otherwise.

Thanks for reporting!